# Type error in render after Promise

Tags: promise, fetch, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm trying to render a component with reason-react after I get data from fetch but I receive a type error. This is my code:

GetData.re:

```
let get = () => Js.Promise.(
  Fetch.fetch("localhost:8000/data.json")
  |> then_(Fetch.Response.json)
  |> resolve
);
```

Main.re:

```
let data = () =>
  GetData.get()
   |> Js.Promise.then_(result =>
      Js.Promise.resolve(
       ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(
         <ItemsList itemsList=result />,
         "root"
       )
   )
 )
```

And I recive this error:

```
29 │ let data = () =>
30 │   GetData.get()
31 │   |> Js.Promise.then_(result =>
32 │        Js.Promise.resolve(
 . │ ...
37 │        )
38 │      );

This has type:
  (Js.Promise.t(list(Item.item))) => Js.Promise.t(unit)
But somewhere wanted:
  (Js.Promise.t(Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t))) => 'a

The incompatible parts:
  Js.Promise.t(list(Item.item)) (defined as Js.Promise.t(list(Item.item)))
  vs
  Js.Promise.t(Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t)) (defined as
  Js.Promise.t(Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t)))

Further expanded:
  list(Item.item)
  vs
  Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t) (defined as Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t))

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I also try to replace render with simple `Js.log(result)` and it works, I try to check type of `Js.log` and `render` (passing their invocation to a function which takes an `int` and watching the error) and they are both `unit`

Where is my mistake? and is there something like toplevel/utop for Reason? It actually helps a lot in OCaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. `Fetch.Response.json` returns a `Js.Json.t` (wrapped in a promise), indicating the structure of the data is unknown to the type system and needs to be decoded. You can do that using [bs-json](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json) for example.
2. `Js.Promise.resolve` takes any value and wraps that value in a `Js.Promise.t`. But since `Js.Promise.then_` already returns a promise, you now have a promise wrapped in a promise. You should therefore just remove `|> resolve` from your `get` function.

The type error tells you about both of these issues (`list(Item.item) vs Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t) (defined as Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t))`), but it doesn't tell you *where* it "went wrong". To narrow down type errors like this you can annotate the type of you functions and let-bindings. For example, if you had annotated `get`:

```
let get : Js.Promise.t(list(Item.item))) = ...
```

It would have shown you that the problem is within the `get` function.

*Rule of thumb: Don't assume, annotate.*

**Edit**: To answer the toplevel/repl question: There is a toplevel for Reason called `rtop`, but it does not work with BuckleScript and JavaScript APIs. There is also the [Reason playground](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html) which does work with BuckleScript and JS APIs, but is not able to load external libraries.